# By using an external framework, Is there a way to have an event always equal to true in the console without knowing the props itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have an input field where when you click it it opens a calendar. This is coming from a library. The problem is that when I want to change the styles of the calendar and check them (props) in the console I can't.

So basically:

1. I click the input field, the calendar opens in a small modal
2. I see a div (referring to the calendar) appearing in the elements
   section in the console
3. As soon as I click that div in the console (element section) the
   calendar disappear from the screen so I cannot check the styles of
   it

So the question is how can I display the calendar as the input field is always clicked by using the console? By using an external framerwork I do not see any onClick events. either any props that set the calendar to open, I tried to force all the element states (options on the devTools to force your input field to be focused:
DevTools force element state) but nothing works. Any ideas? enter code here

[image]
[image]

This is the code:

```
// DATE PICKER
  const defaultFrom = {
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
    month: new Date().getMonth(),
    day: new Date().getDate(),
  };
  const defaultTo = {
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
    month: new Date().getMonth(),
    day: new Date().getDate(),
  };
  const defaultValue = {
    from: defaultFrom,
    to: defaultTo,
  };
  const [selectedDayRange, setSelectedDayRange] = useState(defaultValue);

  /*  const formatInputValue = () => {
    if (!selectedDayRange) return new Date().getDate();
    console.log(selectedDayRange, "day selected")
    return `From: ${selectedDayRange.from.day}/${selectedDayRange.from.month}
    To: ${selectedDayRange.to.day}/${selectedDayRange.to.month}`;
  }; */

  const myCustomLocale = {
    // months list by order
    months: [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December',
    ],

    // week days by order
    weekDays: [
      {
        name: 'Monday',
        short: 'M',
      },
      {
        name: 'Tuesday',
        short: 'T',
      },
      {
        name: 'Wednesday',
        short: 'W',
      },
      {
        name: 'Thursday',
        short: 'T',
      },
      {
        name: 'Friday',
        short: 'F',
      },
      {
        name: 'Saturday',
        short: 'S',
      },
      {
        name: 'Sunday', // used for accessibility
        short: 'S', // displayed at the top of days' rows
        // isWeekend: true, // is it a formal weekend or not?
      },
    ],

    // just play around with this number between 0 and 6
    weekStartingIndex: 4,

    // return a { year: number, month: number, day: number } object
    getToday(gregorainTodayObject) {
      return gregorainTodayObject;
    },

    // return a native JavaScript date here
    toNativeDate(date) {
      return new Date(date.year, date.month, date.day);
    },

    // return a number for date's month length
    getMonthLength(date) {
      return new Date(date.year, date.month, 0).getDate();
    },

    // return a transformed digit to your locale
    transformDigit(digit) {
      return digit;
    },

    // texts in the date picker
    nextMonth: 'Next Month',
    previousMonth: 'Previous Month',
    openMonthSelector: 'Open Month Selector',
    openYearSelector: 'Open Year Selector',
    closeMonthSelector: 'Close Month Selector',
    closeYearSelector: 'Close Year Selector',
    defaultPlaceholder: 'Select...',

    // for input range value
    from: 'from',
    to: 'to',

    // used for input value when multi dates are selected
    digitSeparator: ',',

    // if your provide -2 for example, year will be 2 digited
    yearLetterSkip: 0,

    // is your language rtl or ltr?
    isRtl: false,
  };
```

// component

```
  <DateInput>
    <DatePicker
      value={selectedDayRange}
      onChange={setSelectedDayRange}
      inputPlaceholder="Select a date" // placeholder
      // formatInputText={formatInputValue} // format value
      inputClassName="my-custom-input" // custom class
      shouldHighlightWeekends
      colorPrimary="rgba(4, 173, 147, 255)" // added this
      calendarClassName="custom-calendar" // and this
      calendarTodayClassName="custom-today-day" // also thi
      calendarClassName="responsive-calendar" // added this
      locale={myCustomLocale} // custom locale object
      data-testid="datepicker-input"
    />
  </DateInput>
```

the reasons of checking the style of the calendar is because I need an option where the user can both select one day or a range of dates. But here in order to select just one day I need to double click, because it requires a FROM and a TO date. So I wanted to play with the style as well as with the props to let the user click just once if he does not have a range. In other words, if you click the same day, twice you got a range but on the same date. What I want is a single value when the user click one date and if the user select another date then the range option opens. But not sure how to implement it with this [library](https://kiarash-z.github.io/react-modern-calendar-datepicker/docs/customization) because, first of all I cannot even open the calendar options. does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these options on the devTools to force your input field to be focused:

[DevTools force element state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfQey.png)

Comment: As mentioned in the question I tried to  I tried to force all the element states but it doesn't work:)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see that. Can we take a look at the code for your input field?

Comment: All the code I have is here and comes from the framework:)